# getting column header text inside rowdatabound event

Tags: asp.net, .net

I need to get column header inside  the DataControlRowType.Data of `rowdatabound` event of GridView and here's how I'm doing it:

```
((DataTable)((GridView)sender).DataSource).Columns[i].ColumnName
```

Is there another, possibly more concise than shown above? Just wanted to check out here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header) { 
    LinkButton LnkHeaderText = e.Row.Cells[1].Controls[0] as LinkButton; 
    LnkHeaderText.Text = "Name"; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void gvLista_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < gvLista.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                string cabecera = gvLista.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text;
                if (cabecera.Equals("ofertaactiva"))
                {

                    int activo = int.Parse(e.Row.Cells[i].Text);
                    if (activo != 1)
                    {
                        e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.SandyBrown;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

<del>Here is a way</del>

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "Date";
    }
 }
```

<del>**But the question is why some one would like to change the header name at run-time.**</del>

You can use `bound-field` with header name as follows (need auto generate column to false)

```
 <Columns>
     <asp:BoundField DataField="DateField" HeaderText="Date" 
        SortExpression="DateField" />
 </Columns>
```

### Edit-1

**To get the column name change it**

```
  var columnName= e.Row.Cells[0].Text ;
```

Comment: -1: actually, the OP asked how to _get_ the column names, not how to set them.

Comment: I need to use it in DataControlRowType.Data. So does this mean I'll need a member variable to store it?

Comment: what do you want to do with column name @Rod

Comment: I need to do a lookup with it in a local array

Comment: then get the data-source of the grid-view and use that.

Answer (score 0):

At least in VB.NET 2010 this approach is flawed -- for some reason (PRB?) e.Row.Cells(x).Text = "" in the RowDataBound event.

```
Private Sub gvSymbolList_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvSymbolList.RowDataBound

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Header Then

        Dim i As Integer

        For i = 0 To e.Row.Cells.Count - 1

            Select Case e.Row.Cells(i).Text.ToLower
                Case "symbol"
                    COL_SYMBOL = i
                Case "description"
                    COL_DESCRIPTION = i
                Case "last"
                    COL_CLOSE = i
                Case "change"
                    COL_CHANGE = i
            End Select

        Next

    End If
```